# How to create ajax-style form submission with PHP MVC setup

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using an MVC framework with PHP; standard models/page_model.php, controllers/page.php, and view/page.php.

I have a user registration script (adapted from here:[php-login.net](http://php-login.net) that returns a error messages if the user registers ineligably (e.g. email already taken):

In my controller/register.php, this is achieved as follows:

```
    function register_action() {

    $registration_successful = $this->model->registerNewUser();

    $this->view->errors = $this->model->errors;

    if ($registration_successful == true) {
       $this->view->render('register/success');    //  view/register/success.php
    } else {
        $this->view->render('register/error');  // view/register/error.php
    }        

}
```

In the model/register_model.php script, when an error is created, it exits with a specific error message. E.g.

```
else {
  $this->errors[] = FEEDBACK_UNKNOWN_ERROR
}
```

And this error is then displayed on the rendered view (view/register/error.php):

```
<?php

if (isset($this->errors)) {

    foreach ($this->errors as $error) {
        echo '<div class="system_message">'.$error.'</div>';
    }

}

?>
```

This all works fine. Now, my question: At the moment, I allow users to submit their form from multiple pages. Each time an error occurs, it then renders register/error. How can I actually just have the error return inline with the current page (ie the error message is injected into the current view, ajax style), so that the user does not get sent to a different page?

I do not want them to lose where they are in the site experience. Ideally this would be PHP only, but I'd also like answers involving AJAX if you can be specific about how I should implement the code.

Comment: return a json like this `{error:true,message:"oops error happend",success:false}`

Comment: @arun how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:
in controller - return json encoded array like

```
try {
    if($this->model->registerNewUser())
       return json_encode( Array( "status" => "success", "message" => "Registration successful"));
    throw new Exception("Validation Errors");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
   return json_encode( Array( "status" => "error", "errormsgs" => $this->model->errors ));
}
```

and now your ajax code like this

```
var form = $("#registrationForm");
form.on("submit", function(){
   $.ajax({
       url: form.attr("action"),
       data: form.serialize(),
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data){
            var message = $("<div></div>").addClass("alert");
            if(data.status === "success"){
                 message.addClass("alert-success").html(data.message).appendTo(form);
            }
            elseif(data.status === "error"){
                 for( var error in data.errormsgs ){
                     message.append("<div>"+error+"</div>");
                 }
                 message.addClass("alert-error").appendTo(form);
            } 
            window.setTimeout(function(){ message.fadeOut("slow") }, 2000 );
       }
  });
  return false;
});
```

2 pointers - you better create some ValidationException and throw it, so you don't accidentally catch anything else, and second, you might want to work on your naming
you use camelCase in registerNewUser() but snake_case in everything else, which is not too good for code readability and formatting.

Comment: thanks, i've tried replacing everything inside   function register_action() { with your suggestion and adding the JS as a function inside $(document).ready(function() but it just returns a blank page?

Comment: Can you please provide more info? Because i made an assumption that the return value of your controller goes to output, which is obviously not the case. If not, you just need to dump this json_encoded array into output, and you'll have your message.

Comment: awesome answer... programming in a MVC setup brings out innovative and exciting ideas like the above... just starting MVC with PHP and I'm loving it.